# import class from exterior project in JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In eclipse, I'm trying to import classes from an exterior project A, into a JSP page of another project B.

I created a class in project B in which I call a few A methods, and everything seems to be working well : No errors, results are coherent...

But when I import in a project B JSP like so:

```
<%@page import="com.project_A_package.*" %>
```

and then call a method like this for example

```
<%= Project_A_Class.project_A_static_method() %>
```

Tomcat says that it doesn't recognize Project_A_Class

```
Project_A_Class.cannot be resolved to a type
```

In a second scenario, I even called in the JSP  the class that I created in project B that successfully pulled the results from project A, and this time I get this error (btw, is that "com/project_A_package/Project_A_Class" normal?) :

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project_A_package/Project_A_Class
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.project_B_jsp._jspService(project_B_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project_A_package/Project_A_Class
    com.project_B_package.Project_B_Class.startExternal(Project_B_Class.java:7)
    org.apache.jsp.project_B_jsp._jspService(project_B_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)



root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project_A_package.Project_A_Class
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    com.project_B_package.Project_B_Class.startExternal(Project_B_Class.java:7)
    org.apache.jsp.project_B_jsp._jspService(project_B_jsp.java:73)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

What needs to be done to fix this error please?
Or perhaps what needs to be adapted in Project A in order to be able to be called in project B?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you add that project B as a src ?

Comment: You mean in Project B : Build path >Source>ProjectB/src ? Yes

Comment: Multiple .class files are there it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exporting your referenced project A as a Jar. 
Once done, add this A Jar as well as all other Jar that's used by A to your webapp B's build path AND B's Deployment assembly.

Hope this works for you and that it's not too late an answer!